# insert some data to database file in a form and show this data on another form

Tags: sql, vb.net

i want it like this way

form1 open

button2 click

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

form2 is open

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If kontrol() = 0 Then
        bağlantı.Open()
        Dim komut As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO proje (ad, kod, il, ilçe, adres, firma, yetkili, telefon) VALUES (@ad,@kod,@il,@ilçe,@adres,@firma,@yetkili,@telefon)", bağlantı)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", TextBox1.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kod", TextBox2.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@il", ComboBox1.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilçe", ComboBox2.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adres", TextBox3.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firma", TextBox4.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yetkili", TextBox5.Text)
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefon", TextBox6.Text)
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery()
        bağlantı.Close()
        Form3.ShowDialog()
        Close()
End Sub
```

insert some data in to database on form2 and show form3

in form3;

```
    Dim adaptör As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from proje", bağlantı)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adaptör.Fill(ds, "psanal")
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("psanal").Rows
        'find last entered data and do something
    Next
End Sub
```

i can't find data i inserted on form2 in form3, but if i close form3 and open form3 again then it working. I want do it without close form3 because form3 opening automatically after insert data on form2 and it must show all data in textboxes in form3.

Comment: You could add the data to a persistent DataTable from either form.  No need to run INSERT SQL, let the dataadapter do it for you.  I'd strongly suggest that you lean about form instances and use them.

Comment: Given that you cannot guarantee the order that the data is returned unless you use a `order by` clause in your `Select * from proje` statement. not much you can do.  I AWAYS in EVERY table I create in my database, include two columns, `dateadded` and `datemodified` just so I have something I can use to identify record order and enhance my security and audit trails.  You do not say whether or not you have anyway to identify a record (pk) or record order, so it's impossible with the information provided to identify the last record entered.  Perhaps if you passed a data structure to form 3?

Comment: @ilkay kurt, You have not shown on which event `Dim adaptör As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from proje", bağlantı)` is done on Form3. Is it on Form3 Load or on a button click ?

Comment: On form. Load event

Comment: @Plutonix im not remember if i was tried to use a persistent data table but i Will try it.

Comment: @Prescott Chartier,  i allready have a 'datemodified' column and other columns they have not inserted in form2 they just taking default values in sql.

Comment: @ilkay kurt, ok.  How do you identify the last record entered, by the datemodified?  There's no mention of it in your code.

Comment: @Prescott Chartier code in sql DEFAULT GETDATE ()

Comment: Ok, you have the data and know what the last row entered is, just assign the data in the table columns to the controls (I assume text boxes and/or labels) on the form.